# Why does Spanish use always double reading marks?

Tags: español-neutral

I've noticed that in Spanish, when using an exclamation mark at the end of a sentence, we also need an upside down one at the beginning. The same is the case with question marks.

For example: ¡Adiós! - ¡Hasta luego! - ¡Chao! ¿Cómo te llamas?

1) What is the reason or explanation for this doubling?

2) What is the reason for putting the beginning matk an upside down?

Comment: This question seems to have already an answer in the question linked by @Rodrigo. If the answers to that question do not answer yours, please tell us why not so we can solve your specific doubts.